# How do I Dynamically show the pageSize in yii2?

Tags: filter, yii2, page-size

For now I have set static pagesize in my search function, but now I need to create dropdown for user to change the pagesize from front end. For e.g like 10,20,50,100.

I got the code but it is for yii previous version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I had to do it I will use the following approach.

- Create a Dropdown for the page sizes, you can adjust the dropdown inside the `layout` option of the gridview if you want it between `summary` text and `items` list or add it before the gridview. like this image, you can wrap it with div to adjust the CSS for it yourself.

[image]

The main thing to do is to include the `id` of the drop-down to the `filterSelector` option so that every time the gridview is filtered the dropdown value is also submitted and also whenever you change the dropdown.

Your GridView will look like below

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'layout'=>'{summary}'.Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'myPageSize', [1 => 10, 2 => 20, 50 => 50, 100 => 100],['id'=>'myPageSize'])."{items}<br/>{pager}",
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'filterSelector' => '#myPageSize',
    'columns'=>[
       // your column configurations.......
    ]
]);
```

- Declare a public property in the searchModel

  `public $myPageSize`
- Add that property to the `safe` rules inside your `searchModel`

  `[['myPageSize'],'safe']`
- And then update you `search()` method inside the relative `SearchModel` you are using with the `GridView`. You should assign the `pageSize` option of the `query` inside the `$dataProvider` with the new property defined but make sure you add this line after the `$this->load($params)` statement.

  See below

  ```
    $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = ($this->myPageSize !== NULL) ? $this->myPageSize : 10;`
  ```

Here we are setting the default page size equal to the minimum option inside the drop-down we created, otherwise it would be updated when ever you change the dropdown.

Now try changing the dropdown you will see it working. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Muhammad!
Your answer helped me, but on the layout I had to modify the array for the select:
Where you have "1 => 10, 2 => 20," I had to change it to "10 => 10, 20 => 20,". Otherwise it pagination goes one by one or two by two.

It ended up like this:

```
'layout'=>'{summary}'.Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'myPageSize', [10 => 10, 20 => 20, 50 => 50, 100 => 100],['id'=>'myPageSize'])."{items}<br/>{pager}",
```

The rest worked perfect!